# best practices for database connection file PHP and azure

Tags: mysql, azure

I have a PHP application I am wanting to deploy to Azure via Github.  One of the files is a connection to a MySQL DB, which for obvious reasons, I don't want to have tracked on Github.  The issue I am running into is getting connected to the DB, and displaying my webpage properly, because the connect.php file isn't in Github.  What is the best way to get that to Azure without going through Github?

Comment: You need to use environment configurations so you can upload your database connection string to Azure but not commit it in Github. Depending on the PHP framework you are using, it should be more or less pretty straightfoward. You can research tools like https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/dotenv

Answer (score 0):

In your connect.php file, get your values from an environment variable instead of setting it explicitly. Then, in your Azure portal, go to the web app's Application Settings blade & set your environment variables under the App settings section.